# lenovo z470 keyboard gets stuck

Tags: drivers, lenovo

I installed ubuntu 13.04 64bit on my lenovo idea pad z470. My problem is when I press any of the hardware one-touch short-cut keys for volume control, heat control, etc., my keyboard gets stuck, and I'm no more able to type anything there on.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I was close to commit suicide, there was no solution, but ...

There's a simple "fix" :D

For UBUNTU 13.10:

1. Open your Terminal.
2. `$ sudo nano /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`
3. In nano editor look for "lenovo" section (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>).
4. Add this section (Copy and Paste):

   ```
   # IdeaPad Z470
   keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnLENOVO*:pn*IdeaPad*Z470*:pvr*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
    KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
    KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
   ```
5. Save changes and exit nano.
6. `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
7. restart.

Original Threat:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+question/237756

For UBUNTU 12.04 and 13.04:

1. `$ sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules`
2. Add the following line at the end of the file (but before the LABEL="force_release_end" line.)

   ```
   ENV{DMI_VENDOR}=="LENOVO", ATTR{[dmi/id]product_name}=="IdeaPad Z470", RUN+="keyboard-force-release.sh $devpath common-volume-keys"
   ```
3. Save and exit nano.
4. Restart.

And that's all.

Comment: For people wondering, this is the solution for Lenovo Ideapad users. The first solution works well with Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu 15.10. Read my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 3):

Just upgraded to **Ubuntu 15.10** and this **doesn't work** anymore.

Follow the steps in **Marcelodata**'s answer (first method), but use this fix:

```
# IdeaPad Z470
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnLENOVO*:pn*IdeaPad*Z470*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
 KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
```

Note the change from `keyboard:dmi` to `evdev:atkbd:dmi`