# Laptop Volume media keys stay pressed

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, volume-control

This is a problem I've had before on an old HP laptop. Now I have a Lenovo Z470. These are the keys I mean:
[image]

They seem to be capacitive buttons. When I press volume down for example, the volume goes all the way down and it keeps trying to go down (as if I'd kept pressing the key). Same thing happens for volume up and mute. I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and it stops.

This does not happen if I use <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> (volume down) for example. So I'm guessing it's driver issues.

I found this, but it's really old and I've tried finding the code he's referring to but I couldn't:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=974723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer applies only to Lenovo Z470, but there's probably a similar way to solve for other models.**

Found the answer here: [lenovo z470 keyboard gets stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347576/lenovo-z470-keyboard-gets-stuck)

From that question:

1. Open your Terminal.
2. `$ sudo nano /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`
3. In nano editor look for "lenovo" section (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>). On Ubuntu 15.04 there should be a section similar to the one you have to add but for IdeaPad Z370.
4. Add this section (Copy and Paste) below the one for Z370 (or wherever you think is right :P ):

**Ubuntu 13.10 and 15.04**

```
    # IdeaPad Z470
    keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnLENOVO*:pn*IdeaPad*Z470*:pvr*
     KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
     KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
     KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
```

**Ubuntu 15.10**

```
    # IdeaPad Z470
    evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnLENOVO*:pn*IdeaPad*Z470*:pvr*
     KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
     KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
     KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
```

5. Save changes and exit nano.
6. `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
7. restart.

This was a reported bug for Lenovo Z370 and it was fixed. Unfortunately, not for Z470 (should there be a less specific fix?)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1245189

Comment: Better to submit another bug report for Z470 , to be fix once for all.

Comment: Just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and this **doesn't work** anymore. Follow the steps in this answer, but replace `keyboard:dmi` with `evdev:atkbd:dmi`