# Lenovo Ideapad V330 volume keys get stucked on 19.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, 19.04, ideapad

The volume function keys on my laptop get stucked. I press them once or twice, and the volume goes all the way up or down. Sometimes the keyboard even stops working for a few seconds after that.

I tried the solution offered in the post [lenovo z470 keyboard gets stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347576/lenovo-z470-keyboard-gets-stuck) but it didn't helped.

**Update:** I am no longer having this problem after upgrading to 19.10 beta.

Comment: did you do `# IdeaPad Z470 keyboard:dmi:...` or `# IdeaPad Z470 evdev:atkbd:dmi:...`? the second answer by @Nahuel in the question you linked the correct one.

Comment: Hello, tatsu. Yes, I tried the second answer, but the problem persists.

Comment: did you also replace `...O*:pn*IdeaPad*Z470*:pvr*` with `...O*:pn*IdeaPad*V330*:pvr*` ?

Comment: Thankx, no, I had not changed that. I'm trying it now, and it seems to work. I'll get back to confirm the solution after more testing. Would you care to compile an answer so you can collect the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you read ahead in the answers.

@Nahuel provided an update to the fix :

to sum it up :

For UBUNTU 19.04:

1. Open your Terminal.
2. `$ sudo nano /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`
3. In nano editor look for "lenovo" section (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>).
4. Add this section (Copy and Paste):

   ```
   # IdeaPad V330
   evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:svnLENOVO*:pn*IdeaPad*V330*:pvr*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_a0=!mute
    KEYBOARD_KEY_ae=!volumedown
    KEYBOARD_KEY_b0=!volumeup
   ```
5. Save changes and exit nano.
6. `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
7. restart.

Original Thread:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+question/237756

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, this didin't work for me. It seemed to work at first, the function keys were acting normally, but after a few hours the problem reappeared.

Comment: well that's not that it didn't work. there's definitely something there we should dig into. it didn't momentarily work as a total coincidence.

Comment: Ok, then. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: experimenting with different keywords added to or replacing `evdev:atkbd:` ? this seems to be a question of syntax. also make a bug report on launchpad like they did the first time : https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+question/237756 because if it worked once it can work again. I personally don't have this hardware nor bug so I can't fiddle with it.